# Are all ClamTk Findings safe to remove?

Tags: clamav

I used ClamTK to scan my Windows drive and 2700 files were returned, mostly PUA and install files.  I am new to the program (and Linux) and want to know if there are certain types of false positives I should be on the lookout for?  Or is it safe to remove all of these files?

Comment: This site is about Ubuntu. Knowing, whether files belonging to a Windows installation are safe to delete is not our forte, and off topic here.